# How to use Umlauts from PHP in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, character-encoding, diacritics

I have a MySQL database that contains German Umlauts (ä, ü, ö, etc). The database fields are all encoded latin1_german1_c (if that matters).

From that database I create a json object that I use with javascript. However each value that contains one of those Umlauts gets set to null right from the get go via:

```
var json = <?php echo json_encode($results);?>;
```

then:

```
>>> console.log(json[0].name)
null
```

Do I need to encode my document somehow differently? Do I need to walk through the `$results` array and encode each value somehow? Or something completely different?

Comment: What does the generated JS code look like, from your browser's view-source?

Comment: If you do a "view source" on what gets delivered to the browser, what do you see where you're expecting the umlaut? The short version here is that you need to make sure that the encoding you're telling the browser you're using (UTF-8, Windows-1252, etc.) matches what PHP is outputting. Worth reading if you haven't already: *[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)* This doesn't only relate to the JavaScript on the page; it relates to the text as well.

Answer (score 3):

[`json_encode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) expects strings to be `utf-8` encoded, not `latin-1` encoded - that's why the values get reset to `NULL` (unset).

You need to re-encode the strings from `latin-1` to `utf-8` *before* you use them with `json_encode`. Look for [`iconv`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or the `mb_string` library, both can do that:

```
$utf8 = iconv($in = 'LATIN-1', $out = 'UTF-8', $latin1);
```

Comment: Hakre, thank you very much for the reply. I tried this but it doesn't seem to take on the php-level. $results[0]["name"] is a string that I get from my db that has an Umlaut in it. So I tried this:
    echo $weirdstring = $results[0]["name"]."\n";
    print_r(json_encode(iconv("LATIN-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $weirdstring))); 

this outputs:
    Mörseburg-Baumhauer
    false

Sorry, I seem to be doing something wrong? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Well that looks working, doesn't it? (you can strip the `//TRANSLIT`, that's bogus). Don't forget to encode each `latin-1` string ***in*** the array and then `json_encode` the array, not a single string only. I linked the functions to the manual, so you can learn more about them.